# My scrollView does not wants to scroll

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, scrollview

This is my setup:

[image: setup]

I do not know what I am doing wrong. The image view is bigger than the size of the view and of the scroll view. The constrains are set al followed:

Scroll view: equal heights to View * 0,5, equal width to View, center Y and X to View.

View (inside Scroll view): pinned all zero's inside Scroll view, equal heights and width. I also tried instead of equal heights and widths to center X and Y inside Scroll view, but it won't scroll.

How can I let the Scroll view scroll? Thank you.

Comment: Well, I'm not 100% sure, but it seems that your scroll view derives its content size from its only child - the view that is pinned to it and has equal dimensions. It has no way of knowing that this view has other children that extend beyond its edges. Have you tried placing the child of scrollview in its center, and disabling the pininig to edges? So that it would only have Center x and center y constraints.

Comment: Every tutorial told me to pin a View inside a Scroll view with value's of 0, so I followed that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a *leading*, *trailing* and *top* constraint and *equal height* of `UIScrollView` to superview with 0.5 multiplier. Now to your *contentView* (the `UIScrollView` subview), add a *leading*, *trailing* , *top* and *bottom* constraint. Also add *equal height* and *width* to `UIScrollView`. Set the height to a priority of 250. Add constraints for `UIImageView` inside this *contentView*.

Since the contentView will have a fixed height of low priority equal to the `UIScrollView` height. This fixed height constraint will break once the `UIImageView` total height(based on the constraints you add) will get larger than the `UIScrollView` height and the content will become scrollable. So at the very least you will **always** have a view half the screen size and become scrollable once the content becomes too large vertically.

Comment: I did what you wrote here, however I did it in an other context since I want to give the users to scroll horizontally. Instead of equal height, I did equal width. And instead of setting the height priority, I did it with the width priority of contentView. It won't scroll...

Comment: Well how are you setting the constraints on the image views inside? If i would venture a guess, there should be something incorrect there.

Comment: I did various things, I made the width value extremely large and centered in the View. Another thing I did was centering it in the middle and then pinning it -20 to the right side. All with no result...

Comment: To make the `UIScrollView` scrollable in the approach i mentioned. You need to ensure that the `UIImageView` you add is constrained to the superview on **all** sides i.e. top, bottom, leading and trailing. If you are adding 3 `UIImageView`, the first should have a leading and the third should have a trailing to the superview apart from the other constraints of course. If you wanna center it, add a center horizontally constraint and add leading and trailing of `>=` 0

Answer (score 0):

You need to give contentSize to scrollview.

`ScrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: 1000, height: 500)`

Comment: Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Which constrains have you given to imageview?

set constraint of imageview:

```
 Trailing ,leading,top,bottom - 0 and also give height constraint.
```